# Python find all occurrences of hyphenated word and replace at position

Tags: python, regex

I have to replace all occurrences of patterns with hyphen like `c-c-c-c-come` or `oh-oh-oh-oh`, etc. with the last token i.e. `come` or `oh` in this example, where

- The number of character between hyphen is arbitrary, it can be one ore more characters
- the token to match is the last token in the hyphenation, hence `come` in `c-c-come`.
- the input string may have one or more occurrences of it like the following sentences:

  `c-c-c-c-come to home today c-c-c-c-come to me`

  `oh-oh-oh-oh it's a bad life oh-oh-oh-oh`
- Need to find the start and end position of the matched token via `finditer`

  ```
  r = re.compile(pattern, flags=re.I | re.X | re.UNICODE)
  for m in r.finditer(text):
     word=m.group()
     characterOffsetBegin=m.start()
     characterOffsetEnd=m.end()
     # now replace and store indexes
  ```

**[UPDATE]**

Assumed that those hyphenated words does not belong to a fixed dictionary, I'm adding this constraint to it:

- The number of character between hyphen must range from a minimum to a max, like `{1,3}` so that the capture group must match `c-come`, or `c-c-come`, but not a hyphenated real word like `fine-tuning` or like `inter-face`, etc.

Comment: This can be done with re.sub where the replacement is computed from the match. The pattern would be something like `(([^-]*-)*[^-]*)` and the replacement would be like `m.group().split('-')[-1]`. Untested.

Comment: Do you just want to replace or do you want to do lots of other stuff like find indices, etc?  This seems like `re.sub(r'\b(\S*?-)+\b', '', whatever)` would work

Comment: As for last point I need the `start` and `end` position of each matched token in the capture group.

Comment: I didn't get the UPDATE part. By `{2,3}`, do you mean `c-` can come 2 or 3 times? Then how does that match `c-c-c-c-come` above?

Comment: I mean the group does not have to capture `fine-tuning` or `inter-face`, but only a number of characters between let's say `{MIN,MAX}`, so to avoid real hyphenated words like those ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option using a capturing group and a backreference might be:

```
(?<!\S)(\w{2,3})(?:-\1)*-(\w+)(?!\S)
```

That will match:

- `(?<!\S)` Negative lookbehind, assert what is on the left is not a non whitespace char
- `(\w{2,3})` Capture in group 1 two or three times a word char
- `(?:-\1)*` Repeat 0+ times matching a hyphen followed by a backreference to what is matched in group 1
- `-(\w+)` Match `-` followed by matching 1+ word chars in group 2
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not a non whitespace char

In the replacement use the second capturing group `\\2` or `r'\2`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j9XDOf/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/1wuc2s)

For example

```
import re

text = "c-c-c-c-come oh-oh-oh-oh it's a bad life oh-oh-oh-oh"
pattern = r"(?<!\S)(\w{1,3})(?:-\1)*-(\w+)(?!\S)"
text = re.sub(pattern, r'\2', text)
print(text)
```

Result

```
come oh it's a bad life oh
```

Comment: thanks, I should avoid having arbitrary word length in the hyphen, but with a fixed size let's say `{2,3}` (just updated the question).

Comment: @loretoparisi you mean like https://regex101.com/r/gFeKNh/2/ Does that mean that in `c-c-c-c-come` the `c-` part should not match when using `{2,3}`?

Comment: yes! it works: `print(re.sub(r'(?<!\S)(\w{1,3})(?:-\1)*-(\w+)(?!\S)', '\\2', s))`

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `re.sub()` to replace all without having to iterate over matched indices:

```
import re

s = 'c-c-c-c-come to home today c-c-c-c-come to me'

print(re.sub(r'(\w+(?:-))+(\w+)', '\\2', s))
# come to home today come to me
```

Comment: this works ok, but I need the group start and end as further reference. Maybe I can do this while iterating over the match result?

Comment: @loretoparisi, for that you could do `match` like `re.match(r'(\w+(?:-))+(\w+)', s)`.

Comment: Note: This would also replace `a-b-c-d-come` with just `come`.  Maybe this is what the OP wants, or maybe not.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen let's assume that I must replace these terms with hyphens (like slangs) that I do not have in a dictionary, so it can be `c-c-come` or `c-c-c-come`, or even something like `a-b-c`, even if this is not correct in terms of language of course..so may be I need to add more constraits! than you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible expression:

```
import re

text = ("c-c-c-c-come to home today c-c-c-c-come to me, "
        "oh-oh-oh-oh it's a bad life oh-oh-oh-oh")
pattern = r"(?<=-)\w+(?=[^-\w])"
r = re.compile(pattern, flags=re.I | re.X | re.UNICODE)
for m in r.finditer(text):
    word = m.group()
    characterOffsetBegin = m.start()
    print(word, characterOffsetBegin)
```

Output:

```
come 8
come 35
oh 56
```

Comment: Thanks. Assumed the the number of chars between hyphen has the constraint `{2,3}` let's say, how do I replace `\w` with that, like `(.+){2,3}`?

Comment: @loretoparisi I suppose it would be `r"(?<=-)\w{2,3}(?=[^-\w])"` then, if I'm understanding correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without regular expressions. **Code:**

```
s = "c-c-c-c-come to home today c-c-c-c-come to me"
s = " ".join(w if "-" not in w else w[w.rindex('-') + 1:] for w in s.split(" "))
```

**Output:**

```
come to home today come to me
```

Comment: yes it can, but it's less usable in this case (see constraints above)