# Regular Expression for checking subword between capture groups

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Talking about Regex, I am facing with the problem to replace hyphenations in the beginning part of a composed word.

For example:

`wo-wo-wo-wonder -> wonder
hi-hi-hi-hi -> hi
wo-wo-wo -> wo
f-f-f-fight`

So, for every word inside a text, I want to replace words that before the main word (`wonder`) have a partial or total repetition of the main word (`wo-wo-wo` but also `wonder-wonder-wonder`).
 At the same time, composed words like `bi-linear` or 
`pre-trained` MUST NOT be replaced, because in this case the hyphenation (pre) is not part of the main word (train).

I've seen this solution [[Python find all occurrences of hyphenated word and replace at position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56448068/python-find-all-occurrences-of-hyphenated-word-and-replace-at-position) ] and apparently it can be a good solution.
But my problem is quite different because I don't want to impose constraints about the length of hyphenation, and at the same time I want to check that hyphen is part of the main word.

This is the Regex I am actually using but as explained, it doesn't solve my full problem.

```
re.sub(r'(?<!\S)(\w{1,3})(?:-\1)*-(\w+)(?!\S)', '\\2', s)
```

Comment: If you don't want to touch such as `pre-pre-trained` try [like this](https://regex101.com/r/JoL0k9/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
r'(?<!\S)(\w+)(?:-\1)*-(\1)'
```

or

```
r'\b(\w+)(?:-\1)*-(\1)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QTx2ih/1)

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - a whitespace boundary (if you use `\b`, a word boundary)
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: any one or more word chars
- `(?:-\1)*` - 0 or more repetitions of `-` and Group 1 value
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(\1)` - Group 2: same value as in Group 1.

Python sample `re.sub`:

```
s = re.sub(r'(?<!\S)(\w+)(?:-\1)*-(\1)', r'\2', s)
```